# Dynamically get the endpoint and corresponding wsdl file (from DB) and call on the operation in wsdl file

Tags: wcf, wsdl, endpoint

Dynamically I need to get the endpoint and corresponding wsdl file (from DB) and call on the operation in wsdl file

- The locations of wsdl file and related end points are stored in a DB table for different IDs
- As per the selected id - on click of Start button

  ```
           --> the wsdl file 
           --> its corresponding endpoint
           --> (and already framed parameters on some condition)
  ```

  need to be fetched from Database and the operation available  in the retreived wsdl needs to be called from UI (My UI s ASP.Net MVC 4)

### Sample of DB

ID   |     WSDLLocation    | WSEndPoint  | Active   |  ExceTime   |  ....

My UI displays these in a grid along with a STARTbutton in each row.
On click of this button - WSEndPoint from DB & the related WSDL file needs to be fetched from the specified location 
And the operation in it needs to be called. Hope I have given all required details of my problem.
Pls let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this WCF Dyamic proxy which lets your specify wsdl location:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2008/10/16/dynamic-proxy-and-memory-footprint.aspx

It seems netfx3 is no longer available , all links seems broken ,so you may try this one also:
http://wcfwsdl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=default

Comment: I am new to this. Can you please give a code snippet as a startup for me to use a wsdl to call on a operation declared there.

Thanks

Comment: The links specified here does not have any code of DynamicProxy.
It would be helpful if I can have the source code of it  and code snippet to use this Proxy

Comment: Sorry for delay in response , the last link has source code download link , did you saw that code ?